# When returning a large block of text using Axios and Flask... get Infinity for the innerHTML however in the inspector shows text

Tags: javascript, axios

I have a flask/Guincorn setup..no webserver out front...yet...

I'm making a post call using AXIOS...

```
    axios.post(goto,{},{
        withCredentials: true}

    ).then(function(response){
        console.log('begin response');
        console.log(response.data);
        document.getElementById('resultcol').innerHTML = response.data;

    }).catch(function(error){
        if (error.response) {
            console.log('in error');
            console.log(error.response);
            console.log(error.response.data);
            console.log(error.response.status);
            console.log(error.response.headers);
          } else if (error.request) {
            console.log(error.request);
          } else {
            console.log('Error', error.message);
          }
          console.log(error.config);
    })
}
```

**the returning FLASK/Python CODE on the backend**

```
    test = '222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222'
    response = make_response(test, 200)
    response.mimetype = "text/plain"
    return response
```

**The console from the call**

[image: you can see Infinity in the JSON console log]

**When I look at the preview though in the inspector I see the full text string...**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although the documentation states that the response is not converted. It is converted to a `number` if it can be parsed.

Add `transformResponse: data => data` to request options to disable this behaviour.

```
axios.post(goto,{},{
  withCredentials: true,
  transformResponse: data => data
}
```